# Classes in Java

Tags: java, class, inheritance

I am new in Java so it will be a newbie question, here it is:

I have a class Airplane. But I must have different Airplanes (like PassengerPlane or CargoPlane)
Then I have to use this planes in another class (for example Airport) as Airplane.

I mean, how can I have different attributes (cargoPlane has maximum capacity, passengerPlane has maximum passengers for example) in the same class Airplane?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In order to learn the syntax play around with simple inheritance - but be aware blindly extending classes without consideration (as in some answers here) is not best practice.  I hope the link works but have a read of this:  http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=ka2VUBqHiWkC&pg=PA81&lpg=PA81&dq=favour+composition+over+inheritance&source=bl&ots=yXLoPfp1OY&sig=J6WkbHV-iDAp9HzhewbSD_ig2gc&hl=en&ei=pQl4Tb2IA42DhQf548D9Bg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=5&ved=0CDYQ6AEwBDgU#v=onepage&q&f=false  -  favour composition over inheritance.

Comment: Also recommend Head First Design Patterns as a v. good intro using Java for the examples.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The base Airplane class could be abstract or even an interface.

```
class Airplane{ 
//common attributes
}

class PassengerPlane extends Airplane{
//passenger plane specific attributes
}

class CargoPlane extends Airplane{
//cargo plane specific attributes
}

class Airport
{
List<Airplane> airplanes;
// do stuff with planes

}
```

Comment: Thanks very much. This is what I was looking for. How can I access PassengerPlane's specific attributes from Airport class? For example, I want to see PassengerPlane1's fuel level from Airport? I have tried but it only shows Airplane class's methods (because Airport has list of Airplanes). Is there any way to access PassengerPlane methods?

Comment: It depends on the architecture. In a very simple level, you could iterate through airplanes from the list and check `if(airplane instanceof PassengerPlane)` and cast airplane instance to a PassengerPlane `PassengetPlane pp = (PassengerPlane) airplane;` and access PassengerPlane specific properties `pp.maxPassengers`.

Comment: @EvanBlack - please take note about Design Patterns & consider reading Block 'Effective Java' when you're ready.  This elementary approach does not scale v. well but of course will compile.

Answer (score 1):

Class Airplane should only have the attributes that are shared by all airplanes.  Things like fuelLevel, etc.

And as others have said, the special attributes go into the Subclasses:

```
class Airplane {
    int fuelLevel;
}

class CargoPlane extends Airplane {
    int maxCapacity;
}

class PassengerPlane extends Airplane {
    int maxPassengers;
}
```

Comment: How about one or more interfaces which add behaviours ?